# Configure value using a service constant

Tags: angularjs

In my latest project I'm making some API requests.

As far as I need to setup different endpoints (local development, remote production), I set the value of the used endpoint when defining the app. Everything works just fine.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['lelylan.dashboards.device', 'ngMockE2E'])
  app.value('client.config', { endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000' });
```

The only problem is that I want to set the endpoint `http://localhost:8000` from a service that defines some constants [1]. I tried using the run and config block, but the value is not set. I was doing something like this, without any result.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['lelylan.dashboards.device', 'ngMockE2E'])
  .config(function(ENV) {
    app.value('lelylan.client.config', { endpoint: ENV.endpoint });
  })
```

This looks quite terrible to me, but I've no idea on how to solve this issue.
Thanks a lot.

[1] [grunt-ng-constant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant)

Answer (score 0):

Please see here  : http://jsbin.com/foqar/1/

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);

    var client = {
      endpoint : 'http://localhost:8000'

    }
    app.value('config', client);

    app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, config){


      $scope.endpoint = config.endpoint;

    });
```

or: http://jsbin.com/foqar/2/edit

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.value('config',{client :{endpoint : 'http://localhost:8000'}});

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, config){


  $scope.endpoint = config.client.endpoint;

});
```

Comment: Thanks @sylwester. I'm at the same point. I would love to understand if I can use a constant of a service (ENV.endpoint in my case) instead of setting the endpoint string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the grunt-ng-constant creates a new module file to define the constants. You do not have to bother about it on your app JS file, other than declare the module containing those constants as a dependency.

The below is taken as is on the example config of the [documentation of grunt-ng-constant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant)

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ngconstant: {
    options: {
      name: 'config',
      dest: 'config.js',
      constants: {
        title: 'grunt-ng-constant',
        debug: true
      }
    },
    dev: {
      constants: {
        title: 'grunt-ng-constant-beta'
      }
    },
    prod: {
      constants: {
        debug: false
      }
    },
  }
});
```

In the `options` section, you specify the name of the module, file for the module to be written to and a general set of constants. It works like this,

```
options: {
  name: 'config',
  dest: 'config.js',
  constants: {
    title: 'grunt-ng-constant',
    debug: true
  }
}
```

The above code will become,

```
/*File: config.js*/
angular.module('config', [])

.constant('title', 'grunt-ng-constant')

.constant('debug', true);
```

To change the constants based on your scenario (development / production) you would be using different task sets. Here is where the `dev` and `prod` section comes into play

Considering you are using [ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp), in the [gruntfile.js](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/v0.3.2-release/Gruntfile.js) you have tasks build and compile. The build task is used during development, and the compile gets your app ready to be pushed to production.

In the `build task` you would add `ngconstant:dev` and in the `compile task` you would add `ngconstant:prod`.

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'html2js', 'otherTasksComeHere', 'ngconstant:dev']);
grunt.registerTask('compile', ['clean', 'html2js', 'otherTasksComeHere', 'ngconstant:prod']);
```

For your scenario the code would be as below:

```
/*gruntfile.js*/
grunt.initConfig({
  ngconstant: {
    options: {
      name: 'lelylan.client.config',
      dest: 'config.js',
      values: {
        endpoint : 'http://localhost:8000'
      }
    },
    dev: {
        debug: true
    },
    prod: {
        endpoint: 'http://www.production-server.com/',
        debug: false
    }
  },
});

grunt.registerTask('build', ["ngconstant:dev"]);
grunt.registerTask('compile', ["ngconstant:prod"]);
grunt.registerTask.('default', ["build", "compile"]);



/*app.js*/
var app = angular.module('app', ['lelylan.dashboards.device', 'leylan.client.config', 'ngMockE2E']);

app.controller("appCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "endpoint", 
    function($scope, $http, endpoint) {
        $scope.submit = function(formData) {
                $http.post(endpoint+'/processform.php', formData);
            }
}]);
```

Now it all depends on whether you run `grunt build` or `grunt compile`. *The default task is run when you use the `grunt` command.*

Comment: Hi @dinesh, thanks a lot for your explenation. I actually use the grunt config system as you explained. My problem is to use the constant to setup the client configuration at runtime, as it is an independent module.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use providers. As the docs states:

> during application bootstrap, before Angular goes off creating all
>   services, it configures and instantiates all providers. We call this
>   the configuration phase of the application life-cycle. During this
>   phase services aren't accessible because they haven't been created
>   yet.

For this reason I created a provider to set the needed configurations.

```
<script>
angular.module('app', ['lelylan.dashboards.device'])

angular.module('app').config(function(lelylanClientConfigProvider, ENV) {
  lelylanClientConfigProvider.configure({ endpoint: ENV.endpoint });
});
</script>
```

In this way all services will then be able to use the new endpoint. Using `.value` this was not possible.

Thanks everyone for your help.